# DropDownList in GridView asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

I want to add a dropdownlist to every entry in a gridview.

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">

        <Columns>                
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Bank">
            <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDown"
                AutoPostBack="true" runat="server"  DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Name" 
              >
              </asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

At the back end i have the following code in order to bind a datatable to that dropdown list.

```
DataTable reader = BusinessLayer.BusinessLayerHandler.GetBankList();
DropDown.DataSource = reader;
DropDown.DataTextField = "NAME";
DropDown.DataValueField = "NAME";
DropDown.DataBind();
```

My problem is that the drop down list created at the grid view (DropDown) is not found at the back end as if it doesn't exist..

What can I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `DropDownList` will be created for every single item in the `GridView`, so there *can't* be one field for the dropdownlists. Nevertheless, you can retrieve the DropDownList for a single row (e.g. in `RowDataBound` or `RowCreated` event)

```
protected void grid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{ 
  if(r.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
    DropDownList dropdown = e.Row.FindControl("DropDown") as DropDownList;
    if(dropdown != null)
    { /*  your code */ }
  }
}
```

Or you can use an event of the `DropDownList` itself and access the `sender` parameter.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDown" OnLoad="dropdownLoad" />

protected void dropdownLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
  DropDownList dropdown = sender as DropDownList;
  if(dropdown != null)
  { /*  your code */ }
}
```

Comment: First of all you need to check the type of row you are dealing with. just before  you try to find a dropdown -- if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)

Comment: It's not necessarily needed, but it should be done, that's right... I just edited my answer.

Answer (score -1):

you can find `dropdown` into `grid databound event` by `grid.findcontrol`.