# Select and show selected row to label

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, datagridview

[image]

So, when I click Select I want to show in a Label all datas that contain one row. I have managed to make this, except DropdownList. When I click "Select" it's just empty.

```
protected void GridView_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = GridView1.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex].Cells[1].Text;
        Label2.Text = GridView1.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex].Cells[2].Text;
        Label3.Text = GridView1.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex].Cells[3].Text;
    }
```

P.S.: I have not done this programmatically. The only code I've wrote on .aspx.cs file is the code above.

Comment: what type of `GridView1.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex].Cells[1].Value` do you get?

Comment: @Andrew, NULL as you see it is

(NULL)
2
4

I have Selected the second Row.

Comment: how do you create your control? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305905/dropdownlist-in-gridview-asp-net

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Any other idea? :/

Comment: how do you create your grid and how do you add dropdown to it?

Comment: Nor programmatically. I dragged a GridView from ToolBox, Chose Data Source and binded it with datasource. I edited template, convertet a column into a TemplateField and then added the DropDownliast.
This is the code http://pastebin.com/tEu3HicJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to find the value. its not showing the value because of template field control.
I have used the `gridview` control that you pasted in pastebin.

```
protected void GridView_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e) {

      Label drpValue =
      (Label)this.GridView1.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("Label1");
      Lbl1.Text = drpValue.Text; 
      Lbl2.Text = GridView1.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex].Cells[2].Text;
      Lbl3.Text = GridView1.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex].Cells[3].Text;

}
```